# How can I use a good operator overloading?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class List {
    T* items{ nullptr };
    int count{ 0 };
    int size{ 0 };

public:
    List<T>(const int _size)
    {
        items = new T[_size];
        size = _size;
    }

    void add(const T& value) {
        cout << value << " is added" << endl;
        items[count++] = value;
    }
    
    List& operator =(const List& list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
            items[count++] = list.items[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return count;
    }
    bool operator == (const List<T>& t) {
        for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if (items[i] != t[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool find(const T& t)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if (items[i] == t)
                return true;
        return false;
    }


};

template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, List<T>& list) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++)
        os << list[i] << endl;
    return os;
}



class Complex {
private:
    float real, imaginary;
public:
    Complex() {
        real = 0;
        imaginary = 0;
    }
    Complex(float _real, float _imaginary) {
        real = _real;
        imaginary = _imaginary;
    }
    bool operator == (const Complex& complex) {
        return ((complex.imaginary == imaginary) && (complex.real == real));
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostream, const Complex& complex);
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostream, const Complex& complex) {
    ostream << complex.real << "," << complex.imaginary;
    return ostream;
}

class MyString {
private:
    char* str;
public:
    MyString() {
        str = nullptr;
    }
    MyString(const char* string) {
        str = new char[strlen(string) + 1];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
            str[i] = string[i];
        str[strlen(string)] = '\0';
    }

    MyString& operator = (const MyString& another) {
        delete str;
        str = new char[strlen(another.str) + 1];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(another.str); i++)
            str[i] = another.str[i];
        str[strlen(another.str)] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator == (MyString& string) {
        return strcmp(string.str, str);
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostream, const MyString& string);
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostream, const MyString& string) {
    ostream << string.str;
    return ostream;
}


int main() {
    List<Complex> cList(100);
    cList.add(Complex(0, 0));
    cList.add(Complex(1, 1));
    cout << cList;


    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << cList.find(Complex(1, 1)) << endl;  // true
    cout << cList.find(Complex(1, 0)) << endl;  // false

    List<MyString> sList(200);
    sList.add("abc");
    sList.add("def");
    cout << sList;
    cout << sList.find("def") << endl;  // true
    cout << sList.find("Aef") << endl;  // false

    List<MyString> s2List(sList);
    s2List.add("ghi");
    cout << s2List;

    List<MyString> s3List(10);
    s3List = s2List;
    s3List.add("jkl");
    cout << s3List;
}
```

Hi, I'm studying C++ and I have a question today.
I tried to correct my code but it still said

```
Build started...    
1>------ Build started: Project: study, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------    
1>study.cpp    
1>study.cpp(43,1): error C2679: binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    
1>        with    
1>        [    
1>            T=MyString    
1>        ]    
1>study.cpp(105,7): message : could be 'bool MyString::operator ==(MyString &)'    
1>study.cpp(43,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(T, const T)'    
1>        with    
1>        [    
1>            T=MyString    
1>        ]    
1>study.cpp(41): message : while compiling class template member function 'bool List<MyString>::find(const T &)'    
1>        with    
1>        [    
1>            T=MyString    
1>        ]    
1>study.cpp(132): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool List<MyString>::find(const T &)' being compiled    
1>        with    
1>        [    
1>            T=MyString    
1>        ]    
1>study.cpp(128): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'List<MyString>' being compiled    
1>Done building project "study.vcxproj" -- FAILED.    
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

First of all, I cannot correct my main function. It's kind of skelecton of my code, and my professor said do not change main function and just fix your classes. Thank you for reading my question!! I want your help please.

Comment: `bool operator == (const Complex& complex) {` should be `bool operator == (const Complex& complex) const {` as operator == should not change Complex

Comment: there is you problem with you code first is that you should also overload operator operator[], second is that operator == need to be const function.

Comment: fwiw, the common style is `bool operator==(const Complex& complex)`, while `bool operator == (const Complex& complex)` is uncommon and harder to read

Comment: Danger -- `List& operator =(const List& list) {` -- This will lead to a buffer overrun if `list.size > this->size`.   In addition, there are other glaring bugs in the code.  If you get past all the compiler errors, you will have fun trying to fix all of the obvious bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You miss to include `<cstring>` for `strcmp` (only by chance you did not get an error for that).

When a method does not modify its parameter passed by reference the reference should be `const`. Change:

```
bool operator == (MyString& string) {
    return strcmp(string.str, str);
}
```

To:

```
bool operator == (const MyString& string) {
    return strcmp(string.str, str);
}
```

Only then the conversion from the string literal to `MyString` can be made.

After fixing those, [I am left with](https://godbolt.org/z/sxbPjW1a9):

```
<source>:55:19: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'List<Complex>' and 'int')
   55 |         os << list[i] << endl;
      |               ~~~~^
```

And thats because `List<T>` has no `operator[]` at all.